# storing values in an array using react usestate hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following formik based example where I'm using primereact fileupload.
Everytime user uploads a file, the value of `selectedAssetCategoryId` is different. If a user is uploading multiple file at once then the value will remain the same. For example,
if a user is uploading 3 files together, the value of `selectedAssetCategoryId` will be 1.

So I want to store value `1` three times in `uploadedFileCategory` array.

Is   `setUploadedFileCategory(uploadedFileCategory =>[...uploadedFileCategory,selectedAssetCategoryId]);` a correct way of pusing items in the array? When I'm hovering over the variable `uploadedFileCategory` on this line  `const [uploadedFileCategory , setUploadedFileCategory] = useState([])`, visual studio code editor is telling me that `uploadedFileCategory is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`

```
const DataRequestForm = (props) => {
    const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.loggedInUser)
    const {values, setFieldValue, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleReset, handleChange} = props;
    const growl = React.createRef()
    
     const [uploadedFileCategory , setUploadedFileCategory] = useState([])

    
    
    // fileUpload function testing using new service
    const fileUpload = (e) => {
      

         //Store the values in an array.
         setUploadedFileCategory(uploadedFileCategory =>[...uploadedFileCategory,selectedAssetCategoryId]);
      
        const personnelId = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.loggedInUser).id
        let formData = new FormData();
        e.files.forEach((file, i) => formData.append(`files`, file))

        axios.post('upms/uploadAndCreateAssociations?personnelId=' + personnelId +'&assetCategoryId='+selectedAssetCategoryId, formData,{
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));


        }).catch((response) => {
            growlComp.show({severity: 'error', summary: 'File Upload unsuccessful', detail: 'File Upload was unsuccessful'})
            console.log('Could not upload files.....')
        })
      
    }
    

    

     
    
    

    return (
        <div>
            
            <div id="formDiv">
                <Growl ref={growl}/>
                <Form className="form-column-3">
                                         
                         
                    <div className="datarequest-form">   
                     <label style={{marginRight: '1355px',fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Document Upload</label>
                   
                    <div className="form-field">
                                <FileUpload
                                    name="files"
                                    mode='advanced'
                                    uploadHandler={fileUpload}
                                    customUpload={true}
                                    chooseLabel="Attach Files"
                                    maxFileSize="2058722381"
                                    ref={fileUploadRef}
                                    id="researcherAttachFileButton"
                                    disabled={disableButton}
                                    multiple={true}/>   
                                   
                             </div>

                       
                      
                       
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

};

export const DataRequestEnhancedForm = withFormik(
    
    
    
    {

        
    mapPropsToValues: props => {

              
        
        return {
            
            uploadedFileCategory: uploadedFileCategory
            
        }
    },
    validationSchema:validationSchema,
    handleSubmit(values, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
      
        props.handleSubmit(values)
      
        setSubmitting(false)
    },
    setFieldValue(field, value, shouldVal) {
        console.log('In setFieldValue')
    },

    displayName: 'Data Request Form',
})(DataRequestForm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer this:

**Question 1:**

**Is   `setUploadedFileCategory(uploadedFileCategory =>[...uploadedFileCategory,selectedAssetCategoryId]);` a correct way of pusing items in the array?**

**Answer**
It works and here is the example code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  const changeArray = () => {
    console.log(array);
    setArray((b) => [...array, 1]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Open console to see the logs</h1>
      <button onClick={() => changeArray()}>Example</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The link is currently live at: https://byy0g5.csb.app/
Look at the console to see the logs.

**Question 2**

**When I'm hovering over the variable uploadedFileCategory on this line  const [uploadedFileCategory , setUploadedFileCategory] = useState([]), visual studio code editor is telling me that uploadedFileCategory is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)**

**Answer**
It simply means that `uploadedFileCategory` is not being used anywhere in the code.

Even if the value is correctly set, you need to properly place this in the code to see the changes of value.
Try `console.log(uploadedFileCategory)` to see the output of the code.

Comment: When I'm trying to console log inside `  mapPropsToValues: props => {console.log(uploadedFileCategory);`, I'm getting  `ReferenceError: uploadedFileCategory is not defined`. any idea why it's not accesible over there?I want t send it inside return function.

Comment: Secondly, I used `uploadedFileCategory` inside `setUploadedFileCategory(uploadedFileCategory =>[...uploadedFileCategory,selectedAssetCategoryId]);` Hence I was wondering why it's value was still not used ?